# CSS transition doesn't work in Firefox when position is changed

Tags: css, firefox, transition

I've found annoying bug. I try to animate CSS properties of child elements when at the same time position of parent is changing (in the example it's from fixed to absolute). This works without problem in Webkit browsers, but in Firefox (v. 17.0.1) there's no animated transition.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/chodorowicz/bc2YC/5/

Is there any solution to make it work in FF?

**EDIT**
It's fixed in Firefox 34
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289

CSS

```
#container {
    position:fixed; left:100px; top:100px;
}
#container.some_state_position {
    position:absolute;
}
.box {
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background:blue;
}

.some_state .box {
    background:red; width:50px; height:50px;
}

img, .box  {
    -webkit-transition:all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 1.5s ease;
    transition:all 1.5s ease;
}
img {width:100%;}
.some_state .other_container img {
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Submitted bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=821976

Comment: In Firefox 34, this bug seem resolved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems you have found a good bug.  Although this isn't my favorite fix, it does the job.  Change your button2 to do this on click.

```
$("#button2").on({
    click: function() {
        $("#container").toggleClass("some_state");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#container").toggleClass("some_state_position");
        }, 50);
    }
});
```

It appears for firefox the toggleClass() fires immediately for both classes, causing some issues with the transition effects. Putting the timeout gives jQuery the enough time for it to process what it needs to, in order to do the transitions similar to those in Chrome, etc.  I put the timeout to 50ms, this appears to give it enough time for jQuery to process what it needs to do.  Going lower than that I saw sometimes, it fail and do what you are currently experiencing.

Comment: Heh, yeah, one pesky, good bug. Thanks for finding hack to fix it. I don't know if I'll use it in my case, since it'd require from extra CSS and  JS code and these animations are just eye candies, but it surely works!
I've submitted a bug report to Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=821976

Comment: Still the best solution after more than a year. Thanks mate!

Comment: Nice workaround. And this bug still seems to exist: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289

Comment: I confirm...FF's bug still there :(